# What is the LESS equivalent of declaring var in CSS?

Tags: css, less

I have a scenario to change the branding color and few other styling variables on the portal at run time based on some conditions. I'm able to achieve that 
using CSS (look at the below sample snippet).
But since all our CSS are generated by converting the LESS files at compile time, not sure on how to write a similar logic in LESS so that it generates the CSS like below?

```
:root {
    --brand-color: yellow;
}

h1 {
    color: var(--brand-color);
}

<h1 id="demo">Hello</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

function myFunction() {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--brand-color', 'red');
}
```

Comment: You can use CSS syntax in LESS. When you compile you get the same code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@yellow-color: yellow;
@red-color: red;

h1{
  color: @yellow-color;
  &.red-color{
    color: @red-color;
  }
}
```

Add class instead

```
function myFunction(){
  $("myelement").addClass("red-color");
}
```

Comment: Who said anything about jQuery?